# Renaming files: UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udca9'

Tags: python, unicode

I'm trying to rename files using a Python 3 script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import unicodedata

def convertString(s):
    return unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', s).encode('ASCII', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')

def renameFile(old,new):
    os.rename(old, new)

dir = '/media/alpha/directory/docs/'

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
    for d in dirs:
        normal = convertString(d)
        if normal != d:
            renameFile(os.path.join(root, d), os.path.join(root, normal))

    for file in files:
        normal = convertString(file)

        if normal != file:
            renameFile(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join(root, normal))
```

At some point a string is encountered that throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/alpha/PycharmProjects/rename/findInvalidEncoding.py", line 22, in <module>
    renameFile(os.path.join(root, d), os.path.join(root, normal))
  File "/home/alpha/PycharmProjects/rename/findInvalidEncoding.py", line 10, in renameFile
    print(old)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udca9' in position 60: surrogates not allowed
```

For the most part characters with umlauts, carets, etc. are replaced as expected but clearly there are some problems, specifically with the variable `file` 
in the line `renameFile(os.path.join(root, file), os.path.join(root, normal))`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: No, the error clearly says it's for the line `print(old)`. Which is not in the code you posted.

Comment: Code that matches the error message would be useful, along with the file name  or directory name that caused the error.  I suspect the problem is that the OS is Linux and the `surrogate_escape` codec is involved.

Comment: @melpomene - thanks for pointing that out. I was completely barking up the wrong tree. Once I removed the print statement and put in the rename, it worked.